# Authentication between Desfire EV1 and SAM AV2

Tags: rfid, mifare, sam

I want to Authenticate between Desfire EV1 and SAM AV2 in AV2 mode,
I send the following command between card and SAM but I don't take 90 00 in last command.

(SAM is in AV2 mode of course when it is in AV1 mode I take same response.)
please guide me.

I think I should switch from DES to AES in Desfire but I don't know how do it.

-------------------*Commands*----------------------

```
Desfire Command> 90 1A 00 00 01 00 00 
Desfire Response< BF BC 59 EF B2 90 26 51 91 AF 
SAM Command> 80 0A 00 00 0A 01 01 BF BC 59 EF B2 90 26 51 00 
SAM Response< 10 4C E1 DA F6 A2 E7 51 44 01 86 F3 0D D1 B9 EB 90 AF 
Desfire Command> 90 AF 00 00 10 10 4C E1 DA F6 A2 E7 51 44 01 86 F3 0D D1 B9 EB 00 
Desfire Response< DE E9 3D 38 8B D7 74 3C 91 00 
SAM Command> 80 0A 00 00 08 DE E9 3D 38 8B D7 74 3C 00 
SAM Response< 67 00
```

Answer (score 0):

SAM Command> 80 0A 00 00 08 DE E9 3D 38 8B D7 74 3C 00

SAM Response< 67 00

In this step don't append LE which is 00, because in the previous response from SAM returned AF which means there is additional data to be sent to SAM so we should not append LE.